# SQL How to copy a table to another server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, copy

I'm using VPN connection and remote desktop to login a server and trying to get data from one table.

I tried "Generate Scripts" but it's too large and when I run it at local SQL server (2008), it shows "out of memory". Then I tried to connect to their DB on local SQL Server Management Studio, but then failed because of permission issue. Also, it's kind of impossible to backup the whole database because of its size.

Is there any other method to help me copy from one table to another server? Also, is it possible to back up only at table level?

Comment: Are you able to connect to both servers at the same time from the local SQL SSMS?  i.e., to call `INSERT INTO localdb.dbo.tablename SELECT * FROM remotedb.dbo.tablename`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way for you is:
1. create empty database on the source server
2. copy the table using Export data wizard
3. backup and transfer this database to the second server

Or you can try run Export/Import data wizard and set up source and destination servers, if they are available for you at the same time (if your network configuration permits).

Answer (score 0):

When all else fails, and if possible, create your "create table" DDL script. Run it remotely. Then generate a series of insert statements from your source data. Save the insert statements to a text file. Run the text file remotely.